# Stuck with writer's block; how can my young protagonist overcome depression due to sudden loss of sight?

Tags: short-story, writers-block, ideas

I'm writing a short story in which my protagonist is a little boy. An unexpected event happens and makes his life upside down which is blindness. This latter causes him depression and now I don't know how to make him get rid of this depression.

How can my young protagonist overcome this depression due to their sudden unexpected loss of sight and the life changes that ensue?

Comment: Um... this is not a question. It is a statement. Could you rephrase it so you're asking for help on a specific subject?

Comment: @Nai45 I've made an edit, does it help?

Comment: @uhoh Yes, it does. I have just voted to reopen this question because of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good question this is, you just have to know how to empathize! As I was reading I could already tell, me and you have very much the same problem of writers block and I can help you. Here is my answer...

You need to find something your character loves! Say his mom/dad gave him a braille book or they send him to a school for the blind where he can connect. Humans come out of depression because we find something (or someone) we love or we find good friends who truly understand us.

I hope this helps! (It's my first answer)

Comment: It's totally not that easy

Comment: No, it really isn't, nothing is. To get anywhere you need to work hard, do you think J.K. Rowling had an easy time with the most amazing Harry Potter series? I gave that answer because it's the truth, you just have to find it your self, I have depression right now and I am powering through like a steam roller. I am only happy when I do something I love, it was hard to figure that out for me. Empathy and kindness and giving is what humans are meant for, we are social creatures, introvert or not, love is the answer!

Comment: @DM_with_secrets She's talking about a short story, the literary equivalent of a TV show (solve all the world's problems in 30 min minus commercials).  You're not going to get much better.

Comment: I get you, I tried.

Comment: Sorry, I should have quoted the line I was referring to. "Humans come out of depression because we find something (or someone) we love or we find good friends who truly understand us." Not enough, I promise you.

Comment: @DM_with_secrets you are of course correct, but engagement can still be one helpful step or ingredient, and sometimes an interest can still at least partly emerge from the darkness. From personal experience; finding Stack Exchange *helped* to bring me out of quite a low point in life.

Comment: @uhoh Yeah, I was just having a miserable day/year, and didn't appreciate the implication that I couldn't possibly have something/someone to love and/or good friends.  If I ever get there I'll let you know.

Comment: @DM_with_secrets I hear you :-)

Answer (score 3):

I will try to answer the two aspects of your question.

Particular situation in your plot is probably to benefit from doing some research on what depression is, and how people get out of it. Maybe you can find online or better find a person in your surrounding who had similar or even same issue.

Generally, people get out of depression by accepting their current state and not struggling by wishing it was different or having sorrow for what they have lost. That is a deep transformation which needs to happen within a person to start looking on things from different perspective.

On the writer's block: I guess research, putting things off a bit to cool off, trusting your character and letting it tell you instead of you finding a solution for it, letting things be the way they want instead of finding the "right" thing. Once you free your mind from the concept of doing it "right", you can do it however it works for you as long as it is real in the context provided, and you are the owner of the whole context and the plot within.